# Constructing a closed set of given properties

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to find a set F such that:

(1) F is a closed subset of [0;1],

(2) F contains no isolated points,

(3) Lebesgue measure of F is greater than zero,

(4) [0;1]\F is a dense subset of [0;1].

I was thinking about enumerating all rational numbers in [0;1], taking smaller and smaller open neighborhood around them and then letting F be the complement of the union of the neighborhoods.
It is easily seen that F constructed in this manner would be a closed set of positive measure with dense complement. However, I don't know how to prove that such F wouldn't contain any isolated points.

Answer (score 1):

Take F the Cantor Volterra set (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith–Volterra–Cantor_set). It is closed, its measure is 1/2, and it has empty interior (so its complementary is dense). All what is left to prove is that it does not have isolated points, which you can prove easily using the construction of this set.